# Apply animations on array length change

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

How do i apply an animation every time the array size changes?

I tried to do it this way, but it's not working.

```
<div ngIf="condition" [@heightAnimation]="myList.length"></div>
```

The animation is basically changing the maxHeight from 0 to 100vh on :enter and from 100vh to 0 on :leave and it works when ngIf switches between true and false, but when changing the array length, the animation is not executed.

Does anyone have an example of this animation to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('simpleFadeAnimation', [
      state('in', style({ opacity: 1, height: 100 + 'vh' })),
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 0, height: 0 + 'vh' }),
        animate(200),
      ]),
      transition(
        ':leave',
        animate(400, style({ opacity: 0, height: 0 + 'vh' }))
      ),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  data = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

  add() {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    this.data.push(random.toString());
  }

  remove() {
    this.data.pop();
  }

  removeThis(index) {
    this.data.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-when-removing-jfle8g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Why animation doesn't work with ngIf but with ngFor it does?
I wanted that when the size of the array is changed, the animation will be executed.

Comment: Ngif controls if the element is rendered or not. Animation will read if items have been added or remove to the array[] thus triggering the animation on the item either after adding or before removing it from the array.